# c# Opendialog to load 2 files

Tags: c#

Im trying to use the openFileDialog to load in 2 different files that goes to 2 different area.  I trying doing 2 ways, first i try adding an if statement to see which file they select and use that expression, but it gives me an error.

```
OpenFileDialog opendi = new OpenFileDialog();
        opendi.Filter = "xml|*.xml";



        if (opendi.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            if (opendi.FileName == Hotel_Filename)
            {
                hotelListData = HotelList.HotelLoadFile(opendi.FileName);
                lblStatus.Text = "Success";
            }
        }

        else
        {

            rmtp = roomtypedata.LoadFile(opendi.FileName);
            lblStatus.Text = "Success";
        }
```

and if i do this way , it works, but i have to load the files in the right order, or else if i load the 2nd one first , i get an error. so is there a better method to this?

```
  OpenFileDialog opendi = new OpenFileDialog();
        opendi.Filter = "xml|*.xml";



        if (opendi.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

                hotelListData = HotelList.HotelLoadFile(opendi.FileName);
                lblStatus.Text = "Success";

        }

        if (opendi.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

                rmtp = roomtypedata.LoadFile(opendi.FileName);
                lblStatus.Text = "Success";

        }
```

Comment: Can you think of any way to work on finding out what error it's giving you, and whether the error is at compile time or runtime?

Comment: Runtime.  it gives me "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll"  because it suppose to get deserialized, but it goes in the wrong method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem seems to be with checking the file name. You want to compare only the file name,not all the path. Try this:

```
Hotel_Filename = "hotels.xml"
....


for (int=0;i<2;i++)
{
    OpenFileDialog opendi = new OpenFileDialog();
    opendi.Filter = "xml|*.xml";

    if (opendi.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {

        if (Path.GetFileName(opendi.FileName) == Hotel_Filename)
        {
            hotelListData = HotelList.HotelLoadFile(opendi.FileName);
            lblStatus.Text = "Success";
        }
        else
        {
            rmtp = roomtypedata.LoadFile(opendi.FileName);
            lblStatus.Text = "Success";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nope , i still get the same error. i try doing else if to the 2nd one, it will go through with no error, but when i debug it, it each list show a count of 0, so it didnt load anything.

Comment: This code is fine,it shouldn't throw any exception. So the problem must be in your `Hotel_Filename`.What do you have there?

Comment: const string Hotel_Filename = @"..\..\hotels.xml"

Comment: See my updated answer. Change your `Hotel_Filename` to just the filename(not the path) and check this line `if (Path.GetFileName(opendi.FileName) == Hotel_Filename)`